# how to fix mysql trigger with if else statement?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table up_files and fgusers3. 
the trigger supposed to update fgusers3 after insert on up_files.

up_file: id,uname, days,d_leave
fgusers3: id,name,AnualLeave,cf

I have try without if else statement and working fine. every time user insert data, trigger will update row AnualLeave and row cf in fgusers3 table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_insert`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `after_EL` BEFORE INSERT ON `up_files` 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE fgusers3 
SET fgusers3.AnualLeave = fgusers3.AnualLeave - NEW.days + fgusers3.cf,fgusers3.cf = 0 
WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave'
```

after I add if else statement, I have and error. Please help im new to mysql trigger:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `up_files` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

UPDATE fgusers3 
IF(fgusers3.cf < NEW.days ) THEN
         SET fgusers3.AnualLeave = fgusers3.AnualLeave - NEW.days +fgusers3.cf,fgusers3.cf = 0
       WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave' ;

       ELSE
       SET fgusers3.cf = fgusers3.cf - NEW.days
       WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave' ;
       END IF ;
END#
DELIMITER ;
```

explanation
I try to make if user insert 'Emergency Leave', days will deduct Annual Leave or carry forward (cf)from last year if available. 
if cf available is enough than day, then it will deducted from cf, 
else it will deducted from Annual Leave

Comment: i don't see an else in your second statement?

Comment: You said you have got a error which is?

Comment: if (fgusers3.cf < NEW.days) then
     UPDATE fgusers3 
     SET fgusers3.AnualLeave = fgusers3.AnualLeave - NEW.days + 
     fgusers3.cf,fgusers3.cf = 0 
     WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave'
    end if#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'end IF' at line

Comment: You first query consists of one statement so you can get away with not setting delimiters and using a begin..end block your second query consists of 2 statements so you have to set delimiters and use a begin..end block. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of the `WHERE` clause before the `END IF`

Comment: i have edited the delimiter and still error. 'Sorry an unexpected error happened!'
What did i do wrong please help. :(

Comment: @topak can you please edit your code to make them readable by marking the code block and pressing ctrl_k or inserting 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: Using # as a delimiter is not a code idea since # is used as a start of commment in mysql. Also you cannot use and if condition in an update statement like this and an else if can only exists in and if then. You haven't explained what you are trying to do so that would help as would sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more like what you want.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER test_trig BEFORE INSERT ON up_files 
FOR EACH ROW 
bEGIN   
    IF(fgusers3.cf < NEW.days ) THEN
    UPDATE fgusers3 
        SET fgusers3.AnualLeave = fgusers3.AnualLeave - NEW.days +fgusers3.cf,fgusers3.cf = 0 
        WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave' ; 
    ELSE 
    UPDATE fgusers3
        SET fgusers3.cf = fgusers3.cf - NEW.days 
        WHERE fgusers3.name = NEW.uname AND NEW.d_leave = 'Emergency Leave' ; 
    END if;
end $$

delimiter ;
```

If not then sample data as text in the question would help.

Comment: It work. but when i try to insert the value.#1109 - Unknown table 'fgusers3' in field list. 
:(